# Help with plotting and improving code

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a coupled DDE. Here is my code

```
beta = 0.0005;
lambda = 1;
d = 0.1;
alpha = 0.000001;
a = 0.3;
p = 1 ;
k = 200;
u = 8;
c = 0.2;
b = 0.15;

Module[{sold, τ1 = 10, τ2 = 10}, 
  sold = 
    First[NDSolve[{
      Subscript[y, 1]'[t] == lambda - d Subscript[y, 1][t] - 
        beta Subscript[y, 1][t] Subscript[y, 3][t]/(1 + alpha Subscript[y, 3][t]), 
      Subscript[y, 1][t /; t <= 0] == 1,
      Subscript[y, 2]'[t] == 
        beta Subscript[y, 1][t - τ1] Subscript[y, 3][t - τ1]/
          (1 + alpha Subscript[y, 3][t - τ1]) - 
        a Subscript[y, 2][t] - p Subscript[y, 2][t] Subscript[y, 4][t],
      Subscript[y, 2][t /; t <= 0] == 1,
      Subscript[y, 3]'[t] == k Subscript[y, 2][t - τ2] - u Subscript[y, 3][t], 
      Subscript[y, 3][t /; t <= 0] == 5,
      Subscript[y, 4]'[t] == 
        c Subscript[y, 2][t] Subscript[y, 4][t] - b Subscript[y, 4][t], 
     Subscript[y, 4][t /; t <= 0] == 1
     }, 
     {Subscript[y, 1], Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[y, 3], Subscript[y, 4]}, 
     {t, 0, 200}]];

Plot[
  Evaluate[{
    Subscript[y, 1][t], Subscript[y, 2][t], 
    Subscript[y, 3][t], Subscript[y, 4][t]} /. sold], 
  {t, 0, 200}, 
  Filling -> Axis, AspectRatio -> 1]]
```

I want to get four separate, framed plots. Also, can anybody help me to rewrite this code in more easily understandable way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the subscripts to numerated variables - much easier to read IMO.

```
Module[{sold, τ1 = 10, τ2 = 10, plot}, 
 sold = First[
   NDSolve[{y1'[t] == 
      lambda - d y1[t] - beta y1[t] y3[t]/(1 + alpha y3[t]), 
     y1[t /; t <= 0] == 1, 
     y2'[t] == 
      beta y1[t - τ1] y3[
          t - τ1]/(1 + alpha y3[t - τ1]) - a y2[t] - 
       p y2[t] y4[t], y2[t /; t <= 0] == 1, 
     y3'[t] == k y2[t - τ2] - u y3[t], y3[t /; t <= 0] == 5, 
     y4'[t] == c y2[t] y4[t] - b y4[t], y4[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, {y1, 
     y2, y3, y4}, {t, 0, 200}]];

 plot = Plot[Evaluate[# /. sold], {t, 0, 200}, Filling -> Axis, 
     AspectRatio -> 1] & /@ {y1[t], y2[t], y3[t], y4[t]};

 GraphicsGrid[Partition[plot, 2], Frame -> All]]
```

[image]

Changes to get the boxed separate plots are to map the plot over the desired components, collecting them in the list *plot*, then using *GraphicsGrid* to display.

You can read up on the options for display using it, and check the "see also" there for other options to format sets of plots.

If you want to add labels, you can do something like this for the plot part (which can be extended to arbitrary items distinct to each result):

```
plot = MapThread[
   Plot[Evaluate[# /. sold], {t, 0, 200}, Filling -> Axis, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLabel -> #2] &, 
        {{y1[t], y2[t], y3[t], y4[t]}, {"Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "Y4"}}];
```

Giving:

[image]

Comment: Thanks dear for your time and useful comments. I'm still wondering about the separate plot. Looking for a more attractive graphs. Each one should be boxed separately, with line thickness higher than the default one, with axes clearly visible and can adjust the range more easily.

Comment: It hard to see the full picture because the plots are not showing the full output.

Comment: @mmm: Surely you're not suggesting readers iteratively fix the code at your direction? Consult the documentation re: options for Plot and GraphicsGrid (and the 'see also' within for other ways to format) and give it a whirl. If you get stuck, post back, we're here to help.

Comment: @rasher My issue has been resolved, thanks dear for your helpful responses. Now, to extract data from the above multiple line plot, I used 'Cases' but couldn't succeed. Any comment?